# In the lysogenic cycle, does the provirus split from the cell's main genetic material for replication?

Tags: virology, virus, replication

In a diagram of the lysogenic cycle sent by my instructor in a video, it shows the provirus splitting from the cell's main DNA when the dormancy period ends and the viral DNA is "activated". Is this how it happens, or was he just trying to illustrate the activation?

I guess a better way of phrasing this would be, is the viral DNA replicated as part of the cell's normal DNA, or is it replicated separately?

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the virus is integrated into the hosts genome (and becomes a provirus) it is replicated with the cell genome, since it is now part of it. When the provirus gets activated (this happens by changes in the host's environmental conditions or health), it will get transcribed.
This is followed by the translation of the viral proteins which then leads to a cell which exclusively produces viruses until its resources are exhausted and the cell gets destroyed.